# midi problems audio/midi interface

Tags: audio-recording, audio, midi

I just purchased the Presonis 22vsl audio/midi interface, with studio one artist. I have a KORG MS 2000 , and a Roland MC-505 Groovebox.

I tried several midi configs. Trying to play the Ms2000 as master ... triggering the Groovebox, while still sending midi info to the midi interface.

The weird part is, I can play them all at once if I have the arpeggiater on, on the grovebox. Or if the sequencer is running on the Groovebox, I can then ..still trigger it from the Korg via th THRU port.I can't trigger it at all otherwise.

Basically I'm trying to use the machines the way I was playing them before the interfaces,
triggering the groove box with the Korg.

Now that I've added the fact that I need to send midi out to the midi interface the only solution I could find is midi thru.

Do I need some sort of additional midi interface box ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm only half an inch from understanding what you mean, but I just can't bridge the gap. Can you edit to clearly indicate what the wiring config was before & after? If it's that you previously chained the devices yet now you go through software, check what the software has set for 'through' filters.

Answer (score 1):

Okay the 22vsl only has 1 MIDI input and 1 MIDI output. Correct me if I'm wrong but you normally (before the 22vsl) just simply connected the MIDI output from the MS2000 to the MIDI input on the Roland MC-505, correct?

You would do well to invest in a MIDI timepiece/patchbay; this would solve all your problems and prepare you for the future, as well.

Without getting a Timepiece/patchbay, see if the Roland mc505 allows you to make the MIDI output port a THRU port. If it does, take the MS2000's MIDI out to the Roland's MIDI in and then the MIDI out on the Roland to the MIDI input of your Presonus.

Or if you can set the Presonus to treat its MIDI out as a THRU, you can take the MS2000 to it, then THRU to the Roland. I think this is what you have been trying; either you need to set the Presonus' MIDI out to a THRU, or you need to route the midi signal properly through whatever DAW you're using. I've never used Studio One, so I can't tell you anything about it, sorry. Hope this helps.